# Full Ubuntu Flash Drive install won't boot

Tags: installation, boot

So I installed Ubuntu (full version, not live) onto my 8gb USB flash drive.  When I start up my PC though and go through the boot options the flash drive doesn't show up as one.  I'm not really sure where to go from here.  Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Not all PCs can boot from USB, but may be you just need to enable that option in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Make sure that USB stick is inserted before entering BIOS. And consider that some computers list the USB drives under harddisk, so that one should change **harddisk boot priorities** to enable boot from USB.

(2) How do you install Ubuntu on the USB flash? And consider that the flash will work **only** on the computer from which you installed Ubuntu on it.

Comment: (1) True and useful.  (2) is false. I regularly create full installs of various flavors of Ubuntu on flash drives and use them for diagnostics and repair on systems that have little to no resemblance to the system I created them on.  While there may be the occasional issue with an unsupported network or graphics adapter in my experience those have been few and far between.

Answer (score 0):

1) Prior to creating your flash drive installation, confirm that the [hashes match](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso/503788#503788) on the ISO you downloaded.

2) Choose "something else" from the installer menu

3) Install normally insuring that you are targeting the flash drive.

4) Choose the flash device for the GRUB boot record installation.

I've followed this approach many times with Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, and Mate.

If for some reason your new flash system doesn't boot, double check the hash for the ISO and replace it if the hash doesn't match and start over. If the hash matches, try to [repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows?lq=1) or [reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493612/how-to-reinstall-grub) grub.

Source: Experience