# MD5 hash for ubuntu .iso (14.04 through 18.10)

Tags: iso, checksums

I cant find the MD5 hash for ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso on [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) website.

Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to find the checksums of Ubuntu ISO images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9417/where-to-find-the-checksums-of-ubuntu-iso-images)

Comment: There's no reason to keep a copy of MD5SUMS on this site, or a link to each release's MD5SUMS.  [Eliah Kagan's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/339857/158442) very clearly explains how to look up the hashes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. they are not the same. 
The Md5sums for 14.04 releases are as follows:

```
 dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153 *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
 c4d4d037d7d0a05e8f526d18aa25fb5e *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
 01545fa976c8367b4f0d59169ac4866c *ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso
 08d25bf879e353686a974b7b14ae7d81 *ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.iso
 119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd *ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
 a4fc15313ef2a516bfbf83ce44281535 *ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
 ca2531b8cd79ea5b778ede3a524779b9 *ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso
 3aa14ca13d52df070870d39306f4a4eb *ubuntu-14.04.1-server-i386.iso
```

The md5sums for 14.10 are as follows:

```
08494b448aa5b1de963731c21344f803 *ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso
4a3c4b8421af51c29c84fb6f4b3fe109 *ubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386.iso
91bd1cfba65417bfa04567e4f64b5c55 *ubuntu-14.10-server-amd64.iso
1c920941d2544c0e097deb79cf3ebfbd *ubuntu-14.10-server-i386.iso
```

The right place to look is one of the sources below **(If you are detecting a pattern here, you're right in that the link is http://releases.ubuntu.com/*version.number*/MD5SUMS. where *version number* is yy.mm of the release in question.** You can also find md5sums for the following at the aforementioned link.

```
Edubuntu
Kubuntu
Lubuntu
Mythbuntu
Ubuntu GNOME
UbuntuKylin
Ubuntu MATE
UbuntuStudio
Xubuntu
```

Sources:

- [14.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS)
- [14.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/MD5SUMS)
- [15.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/MD5SUMS)
- [15.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/MD5SUMS)
- [16.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/MD5SUMS)
- [16.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.10/MD5SUMS)
- [17.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/MD5SUMS)
- [17.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10/)
- [18.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/)
- [18.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/cosmic/)

The md5sums for recent Ubuntu versions including Lubuntu Kubuntu Xubuntu, etc. can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) and previous and point releases and their md5sums can also been found on [this page.](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/) Drill down through version into release (or source) to find the sum (hash) for your version.

You can check the hash (md5sum) with the command `md5sum ubuntu-version-desktop-variant.iso` on a Linux system (Changing the name of the ISO file to match the one you have).

You can check the ISO under Windows using the built-in command [certUtil](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c854b85-bacc-4ffb-a9aa-fd2ed4f5eafa/certutil-hashfile-md5?forum=winservergen) (included in Windows 7 or newer), or you can use either the MD5 & SHA Checksum Utility available [here](http://download.cnet.com/MD5-SHA-Checksum-Utility/3000-2092_4-10911445.html) or the Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier available [here.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533)

Comment: Is there a safe source? That one is fine, but I would like to access that kind of information using https

Comment: Do you know where we can find MD5 sums for other distros such as Lubuntu?

Comment: @ElderGeek The link is for 14.04, not for 14.04.1. I found the [Lubuntu hashes](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/MD5SUMS) with the help of Google. I also found two relevant bug reports, one [for Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1349715) and one [for Lubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1356023).

Comment: @PaddyLandau Thank you. I incorporated the information into my answer