# Ubuntu boot error premature end /casper/vmlinuz.efi

Tags: boot

I'm trying to install ubuntu and when I click on the try ubuntu before installing one it gives me this error

Error: premature end of file /casper/vmlinuz.efi.
Unaligned pointer 0xc0512c0B
Aborted. Press any key to continue

This is my first time using Linux and needless to say I am very confused on what to do right now.

Edit: Version 14.04

Comment: Probably some error happened when you created the bootable USB/CD. Try making one again.

Comment: Please identify the version of Ubuntu you are trying to install. you should check the md5sum to insure your copy is correct before making a coaster by burning a bad copy to disk again. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-14-04-1-desktop-amd64-iso/503788#503788 for md5sums and how to find them for recent versions of Ubuntu

Comment: I too am getting this error, on any .iso grub2 tries to boot.  UEFI,GPT,64bit AMD. Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 1):

The file `casper/vmlinuz.efi` is the Linux kernel on the installation medium. So if you're getting this error, it's a problem with your USB flash drive.

To fix it, I formatted my USB flash drive and copied my Live CD back onto it. That fixed it for me and, if that helps you, please mark this answer as correct. Thank you!