# 64-Bit installation only gives my a 32-bit OS

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I recently decided to install Ubuntu on my computer for a project I'm doing, I downloaded the 64 bit version of Ubuntu from the official website and burned it onto a DVD, however, after the installation, I noticed (through the system settings) that the OS was only 32-bit

In case I had made the mistake of accidentally downloading the 32-bit ISO, I went to the Ubuntu website and downloaded the 64-bit version and burned it to a memory stick. I then proceeded to re-install the OS, but it still gives me the "32-bit" in the system settings.

Can someone please tell me What I am doing wrong?

Although I am certain that my PC architecture is 64-bit, I'll include details of my setup, just incase you think I may have made a mistake:

Processor: AMD A6-5400K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2 (in other words, its a dual core)

Motherboard: Asus F2A85-M PRO

Ram: 2x Kingston 4GB DDR3

Also, I got the .ISO from this address:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Iso name: ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please edit your post and add the filename of the ISO you downloaded and the link you downloaded from to your post.

Comment: @ElderGeek Ok, I have updated this post, you can find where I downloaded this from and the .iso image name just underneath my PC specs :)

Comment: use this [link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso).

Comment: @Mitch Thanks, but I already added that to my Post

Comment: add the output of `uname -a` please

Comment: @Shutupsquare I'm sorry, I don't understand, Im fairly new to Linux btw

Comment: Okay just open a terminal, and type `uname -a`

Comment: Then add the output of that to your question.

Comment: Downloading the 64-bit ISO from the link you provided and checking the md5sum matches  119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd

ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso. Why do you think you have a 32 bit OS? Are you possibly dual booting both 32 and 64 bit versions?

Comment: @Shutupsquare OH! you mean run that command in the terminal and tell you the output! jeez I have a long way to go with Ubuntu :/ Anyway, the output is as follows: "Linux Arcade 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:31:23 UTC 2014 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux"  Where it says 'Arcade' is the name of my Computer, as that's the project i'm using it for :)

Comment: @ElderGeek When I go to the 'Details tab in the system settings, it tells me that my OS type is 32 bit

Comment: Open a terminal enter the directory that you downloaded the iso to and and issue the command md5sum `ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` and add the result to your question. Thank you!

Comment: @ElderGeek Ok then, I shall re-burn the ISO to my memory stick (making sure its the amd64 version this time) and shall attempt to re-install the OS, I'll let you know how I get on. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your uname output indeed indicates a 32 bit OS, It appears that you accidentally flipped the dropdown on the page you provided from 64 to 32 bit.

My uname output from the 64-bit ISO link that you provided ends with X86_64.

You should check the md5sum of your download to insure it matches before you re-burn.

You can find references to the md5sum here: [MD5 hash for ubuntu .iso (14.04 through 16.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-14-04-1-desktop-amd64-iso/503788#503788)