# Unable to install Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, usb-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 14 LTS iso. I used Universal USB Installer (UUI) to make a live Ubuntu USB. I then rebooted to it. I got a boot menu with menus like: `Try Ubuntu without Installation`, `Install Ubuntu`, `Boot from first Harddrive`, ...

But once I select a menu to boot, the computer halts and accepts no further input (It rejects it with a beep) and hangs up on with that boot menu.
 How can I install it?

Then I tried with flashBoot. Now, it shows that `Unknown keyword in the configuration file :ui`
My computer don't have support for pae.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Documentation on the process can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation Also, you should check the md5sum of the downloaded ISO before attempting to install to insure your copy is correct. More info on that can be found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-14-04-1-desktop-amd64-iso

Comment: Unable to find a solution

Comment: Did you verify the md5sum on your ISO matches? If not you need to start over. we already know you have been unable to find a solution or you likely wouldn't be here asking for help. What we don't know is: Do you have a valid ISO? Does your system meet minimum system requirements? What you've tried and the results of those attempts. Please help us help you by editing your question to include further information that only you have. Please review and follow the guidelines here: http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My computer don't have support for pae. From some external resources, I found that its the fault causer

Comment: "My computer don't have support for pae." belongs in your question. Please edit your question and add that information along with anything else that seems relevant! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu no longer maintains a non-PAE kernel.  There is however still a method to install **L**ubuntu (the **L**ittle brother of Ubuntu: **L**ower RAM, **L**ower CPU, ...)

And they have a solution called [Fake-PAE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu-fake-PAE) which can still be installed on older hardware.

Comment: And as you're a reputation 6 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)