# Will a Ubuntu install disk made on Windows run on a Mac?

Tags: system-installation, windows, mac, macosx, burning

I want to install Ubuntu on my Mac, as a second OS, I know how to do it, but will a DVD burned on Windows work on my Mac?

Comment: It should work fine. Make sure you double check the ISO and make sure the md5 matches so you don't burn a coaster. More here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso/503788#503788

Comment: Should work fine, I am just going to state from experience, *do not delete your EFI partition or your mac partition*. You will need both to make your mac hardware work. It seems silly but deleting either partition will cause more headache then you can imagine. Instead, make your OSX partition really small (just big enough) by shrinking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, so long as you burn the `.ISO` image properly there is no reason why the Windows burned image of a Linux operating system wouldn’t work on your Mac... Aren’t computers just amazing!

Comment: **“Aren’t computers just amazing!”** Yes, when developers are thoughtful and understanding about the needs of end users and care about quality. Which is why when Windows users are worried about things like this, they are just too worried about the world of nonsense Microsoft artificially forces upon their users for little to no reason.

Comment: I could not agree with this statement more!  The one thing that I give credit to M$ for is not entirely locking their users into an ecosystem.  Unlike Apple products that decide what you are allow to install and use, at least on mobile products anyways.  Wish the whole world would just use open source Linux solutions;)

Comment: @JakeGould I'm also not so sure that Microsoft created their "world of nonsense" completely on purpose. Windows is not a unix based system, the only non-unix system with a relevant userbase to be precise. This causes a whole lot of issues with compatibility. True, Microsoft created this whole crap, but it did allow them to advance the world of operating systems astronomically. If they didn't create windows (with all it's quirks), then OSx wouldn't exist as it does now, and ubuntu desktop would look a whole lot different.

Answer (score 0):

Short : It will definitely work.!!

Long: What's the link between Mac and impact of Windows when your burned disk has Ubuntu specific to Mac.

Some burn disc specific to PS4 or Wii or even DVD player (remember dvd with menus which won't play in any other) on either windows or Mac and they do work!!

So go ahead!!

Comment: This was selected as the best answer and within an hour it was changed. Don't know if the questioner had some dilemma :)