# Lenovo G580 sound only via headphone plug and freezes

Tags: sound, alsa

Hello Ubuntu Community,

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, because I got sound problems under Windows 8.0 and 8.1. The first Ubuntu Installation went wrong and the second try worked finally.

But later on I noticed that Ubuntu had only detected the headphones (wich were not connected) and not the internal Speakers. 
I also had that problem at Windows 8.0 and 8.1 and couldn`t figure out how to fix it.
Now is the current Ubuntu Installation very unstable and freezes sometimes.

1. Should I reinstall?
2. If yes, should I try to install Linuxant HDA Drivers (Conexant HDA Driver)?
3. Check or reinstall ALSA?

EDIT:

Thank you for your answer!
What do you mean with MD5 Hashes and how can I execute them?

Output of "lsb_release -a":

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Release:        14.04

Codename:       trusty

EDIT 2:

Ubuntu freezed again and had to do an Alt+Ctrl+F1 and Alt+Ctrl+Del.
Now I`m sure, that my installation was corrupt.
Could you please tell me how to use these MD5 Hashes? And wich one should I pick?
Now I noticed that I got two errors at boot, but they were shown too short (under 1s).
Please help me!

Comment: Prior to installing you should always insure that you have an uncorrupted ISO. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso/503788#503788 Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought the Linuxant HDA Drivers were for softmodems, not sound cards so that doesn't sound helpful.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com! Please [edit] your question and include the output of `lsb_release -a` as well as `aplay -l` Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the system after installation? & After that look for the additional drivers in update settings.

Comment: The problem is that my Chipset is recognized as an Intel Corporation: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller. But the Chipset is an Conexant CX20590.

Comment: Oh and yes after installation of Ubuntu 14.04.2 updates came (about 300 MB).

Comment: So after finding out that after changing of the audio driver to not use, that the audio output was still recognized as headphones (no headphones were plugged in).