# Not booting any operating system

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) along with Windows 8. When I install it I give it just a 7 GB partition. After five days the Ubuntu partition is completely full (low space).

So I just booted into Windows 8 and deleted the Ubuntu partition and  created a 40 GB partition for Ubuntu. When I restarted the PC to install Ubuntu 14.04 on that partition again, I got this message:

```
error no such partition grub rescue
```

I am getting this type of message on every boot. Now I am not able to boot into Windows or Ubuntu. Why?

This has happened after deleting the Ubuntu old partition. I don't know what to do now. I don't have any CD ROM in my PC.

How should I proceed to install Ubuntu again?

Comment: Can you boot to a live USB to re-install Ubuntu?

Comment: You are getting this error message because you have deleted the Ubuntu partition which stores the grub configuration files in `/boot/grub` which lets your computer boot either Windows or Ubuntu. To fix it you either boot repair Windows from recovery if you have one which will allow you to boot Windows again or reinstall Ubuntu using a live-USB like Organic Marble suggested and you will be able both Windows and Ubuntu

Comment: As @OrganicMarble suggests you can boot from a live media (USB flash drive) in order to re-install Ubuntu. Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu  and http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported  You may have to borrow another system to create your live media. Also make sure the hash matches on the downloaded ISO prior to creating your live media. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso/503788#503788

Comment: @rajkumar you can not install Ubuntu using `wubi` in windows 8.

Answer (score 3):

When you installed Ubuntu after Windows 8, you also installed the [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) bootloader which is handled by the Ubuntu GRUB manager which lets you select which operating system to boot. In your case, either Windows or Ubuntu. When you restarted your computer after deleting the Ubuntu partition it is searching for GRUB, but you deleted it. That is why the problem is occurring.

Solutions:

1. As your PC don't have a CD-ROM drive, you can make an Ubuntu bootable USB pendrive by burning the [ISO image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) file of Ubuntu on to the pendrive (as your PC is not working, you have to use another PC). Then install Ubuntu again on that 40 GB partition with that pendrive. Therefore you can see your Windows and Ubuntu again.
2. If you don't want to install Ubuntu, then the most straightforward solution is installing Windows again. As you don't have a CD-ROM drive you can follow solution 1 to install Windows using a pendrive.

Comment: He shouldn't have to reinstall Windows 8, since he was able to use it before when he removed the Ubuntu partition. Windows Boot Manager should still be present on his machine.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You see I have mentioned solution 2 as most straightforward solution. Retaining the Windows boot manager is little bit complex solution for a person who doesn't know why this PC isn't booting up.

Comment: I'd disagree, simply because navigating a BIOS/UEFI is just not that difficult of a task even for a newbie. Those low level systems aren't designed to be confusing. Reinstalling an entire operating system is a bit of a drastic measure; all things considered, this person probably wants to keep all their files and configurations that already exist under their Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

When you deleted your Ubuntu partition, you also chucked out your GRUB installation. GRUB is the bootloader for your machine which lets you boot into either Ubuntu, Windows, or any other present OS.

To boot back into Windows, you should be able to interrupt your boot and enter the UEFI by pressing one of the following common keys after powering on: `F1` `F2` `F10` `F11` or `ESC`. Which one works will depend on your laptop's make and manufacturer.

Once in UEFI mode, navigate to your boot options and move `Windows Boot Manager` back to the top of the list. Saving your changes and rebooting your computer should result in loading Windows. Once in Windows, [download an Ubuntu 14.04 ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) and burn it to a USB drive using the tool of your choice.

Shut down your computer and turn it back on, then select the Ubuntu Live USB as a temporary boot device (press `F12` typically at boot, or reorder your boot devices in UEFI). Follow the instructions for a dual boot system presented at the install screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ubuntu [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) and then use the **[GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted)** partition editor to set the boot flag to your Windows partition. (Right click on the Windows partition -> Manage flags -> Boot). This will let you boot Windows (like having a single Windows OS).

Afterwards, install Ubuntu again (as you did before to get a dual-boot system), this time using the bigger space.