# Installation doesn't begin

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, rufus

I downloaded `Ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso` from Ubuntu's downloadable torrent and wrote it on a 4GB flashdrive using `rufus-2.8` on a Windows 7.

So I get to the BIOS and set to boot from the USB. On boot, I get to a screen where there's nothing but sort of a keyboard with the letter "H" next to a person within a little circle. If I do nothing or take too long to press H, system just stops responding.

Restarting and quickly pressing <kbd>H</kbd>, a language menu shows up and I select Português do Brasil, my mother tongue. Then is shown 5 options - Try without installing, install, check disk, test memory and boot from 1st HD.

No matter what what option I choose, there's a `_` sign in the top left corner, blinking non-stop. After that nothing happens. On previous attempts, with different versions, same happens.

This is my system:
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 DUo CPU  T6600 @ 2.20GHz
4,00GB RAM
Windows 7 Starter SP1

Comment: Im a total novice but I had success with: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 to the desktop. Then I used the above software to create a bootable usb. Changed boot sequence to start with usb. Restarted and Ubuntu gives you the option to run off usb or install OS on the computer.

Comment: Try Unetbootin https://unetbootin.github.io/ to prepare your USB and tell the result.

Comment: So I booted and the 5 options showed - this time, when selecting an option, there was the same "_" symbol blinking, only this time the rest of the screen was light grey instead of the previous black.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem one time a go when .ISO was corrupted. Try to download it once again, or [check MD5sum.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso/503788)