# I created a usb bootable stick with ubuntu on it.but when i try to install it on my dell computer,it shows an error

Tags: system-installation

the error appears as

"(initramfs) mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: Invalid argument

Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs"

Comment: I think something is not going properly or correctly mounted on the stick.
You should try Rufus to create the bootable stick.

Comment: You may have created the stick using a corrupted ISO. I recommend checking the hash of the ISO prior to commiting to the live media. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso

Answer (score 0):

When you download the newer Ubuntu isos, they don't have Wubi anymore, preventing you from installing Ubuntu.