# Ubuntu 16.0.4 Blackscreen and Blinking Cursor

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, cursor

I just installed a 3rd hard drive on my computer specifically to act as a bootable Ubuntu environment completely separate from my windows installation.

This is my first time installing Ubuntu and I've found one problem that I cannot solve. I'm installing it off of a bootable USB flash drive.
I don't reach any option menus or the likes, it just crashes to that before I can even do anything.

I went into the /boot folder of my bootable USB flash drive and then the grub folder and edited the "Install" selection in grub.cfg and loopback.cfg to remove quiet splash and replace it with nomodeset and nolapic. It seems to have absolutely no effect on my installation.

EDIT: SOLVED! I switched to using Linux Live USB to make my bootable disc, and now it works like a charm.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include which fixes you tried that did not work. Thank you for helping us help you! My best guess at this point is that you have created your live media using a corrupt ISO.  To check it see http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso/503788#503788

Comment: Identify your hardware and it sounds as if your graphics card is not linux compatible.