# How to boot a system from pendrive in EFI mode succesfully?

Tags: live-usb, grub-efi

During last week, I tried to install Ubuntu for few newcomer friends. I know two method to make a bootable Flash USB through Linux. One is famous method of "DD" and other one is Unetbootin. But I got failed for each time I tried one of these methods to bring system in EFI mode up(and when it starts in UEFI mode it fails to install because of different reasons such as having another distro installed in EFI). So I had to use the software "Rufus" in windows to make a bootable flash USB and it worked in EFI mode. But I don't want to use Windows each time just only to make a Flash USB bootable properly. Do you have any serious advice?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? the dd approach works fine on current images when booting via both  EFI and Legacy BIOS . My first question would be did you check the [hash](http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso) to insure you had a good image prior to committing it to the pen drive?

Comment: Will not boot in BIOS mode
UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formated flash & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media
UEFI only bootable flash drive
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2299040

Comment: @ElderGeek Yes I have checked it. And indeed I installed a fresh Ubuntu from same ISO by using Rufus. DD works properly in UEFI mode for me.  But I have installed Antergos in EFI mode which enforces me to install Ubuntu in same mode as well.

Comment: Why this question has been marked as duplicate of UEFI-only bootable mode? That's nonsense. I'm asking that when I'm trying EFI mode, the methods I know are not working.