# I cannot boot UBUNTU 16.4 from my hard drive after installing with a USB stick

Tags: boot

I installed UBUNTU 16.4 using a UBS stick and now after I cannot boot from the hard drive but only can use "try UBUNTU..." and boot from the USB...Why

Comment: Why? Because you're still booting from the USB. You need to remove the USB and/or change the boot order in BIOS/UEFI back to the the drive where you installed.

Comment: Some 30 minutes ago you posted a question that implies you had a working OS. Did you just reinstalled and the previous installation wasn't done by you? It sound like you're doing it for the first time and yet your previous questions suggest otherwise.

Comment: You need to remove the installation medium or change the boot medium priority in BIOS. This is explained in  [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

The possibilities are as follows:

1) You failed to remove the installation media when prompted to by the installer and your system is still set to boot from USB.

2) Your hard drive has failed and 1 is also true.

3) You neglected to [verify the hash](https://askubuntu.com/a/503788/225694) of your ISO and have managed to install a corrupted operating system.

These possibilities are in order of likelihood.