# How can I tell if I have downloaded 64 bit?

Tags: 64-bit

I am completely new to Ubuntu and this forum.  I've just gone through the process for a free download of Desktop LTS, for the purpose of establishing a MythTV set-up on my home. 
The MythTV instructions suggested using a 64 bit version of Ubuntu, but during the  free download steps, I did not see any option to select this, except in the "other options" category under bit torrent, which seemed to require a fee.
Can anyone explain how I tell which version I have downloaded, or how I can make certain I get the 64 bit?  Please excuse me if these are elementary questions...I'm really feeling my way here.
Thanks,
Peter

Comment: FYI, there's no fee although [donations are accepted.](https://community.ubuntu.com/help-information/funding/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the .iso file you downloaded has "amd64" in the name, it's 64 bit. If it has "i386" in the name, it's 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell whether you have the 64-bit version by checking for the string "64" in the ISO filename. You don't mention where you obtained your ISO, but regardless I reccommend that you [check the hash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso-14-04-through-16-10/503788#503788)

The ARM and Power PC 64 bit versions [available here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/) also have "64" in the ISO filename.

Comment: Thanks very much for your responses.  I'm embarrassed to admit it, but I'm still struggling to grasp what an "iso" actually is....however, thanks to your pointers, I have managed to confirm, by opening my burned disc, that what I downloaded is the "amd64" version!  That's one challenge surmounted.

Comment: Hopefully [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) will end your struggle. :-)

Comment: @PeterC I'm glad it helped [Upvoting](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [accepting](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) answers is how we express our thanks here. This approach helps others with the same issue find answers that work. Once you've reached 15 reputation you'll be able to upvote, meanwhile, I would encourage you to accept the answers to your questions that are most useful to you.  This results in a in increase in reputation as outlined in the accepting link above.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't picked that up.  I've now addressed it!

Comment: No worries @PeterC Welcome to the community!