# Ubuntu installation issues on Dell Inspiron 15 i7559

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, dell, 16.10

I have been trying to setup a dual boot on my laptop, I can't seem to get much past the install.

In order to start the install I need to pass `nomodeset i915_bpo.nomodset=1` in grub. After the install 9 out of the last 10 tries (yes I have reinstalled 10 times, minimum) it will hang during boot. The 1 time it booted, I tried to follow a guide made installing Ubuntu on this specific model and essentially after setting up the Nvidia drivers it decides to take a dump again and I can't even get it to boot.

Can anyone give a last minute suggestion before I give this one last shot?

I would prefer Ubuntu GNOME, but I guess anything that will let me get a fully operational system would be great. I have been trying with 16.04 and 16.10, if there is another version I can try for the initial install then I will give it a roll.

Comment: Have you tried disabling Optimus in the BIOS? Have you tried booting in legacy mode?

Comment: Yes to legacy, and no to Optimus.. Didn't know that was an option.

Comment: Just checked, didn't see any way to disable the Optimus in the BIOS.. Will do some more research and see what I can find.   edit- apparently this is no official way to disable it..

Comment: Some laptops that comes pre installed with Windows has a feature called  "secure os= only let windows OS boot" something like that! If you see that! Disable it!

Comment: The fact that you've experienced a hang during boot after install most times and not all times leaves me with questions. Did you by any chance [verify your ISO](http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso-14-04-through-16-10) before creating your bootable media? If so, does try Ubuntu work? If so, is your [installation drive in good shape?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-10/528077#528077)

Comment: Apparently I had it working then did a test reboot and it hung again. I did manage to get a message stating "A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (5min 55s / no limit)