# Hard disk corruption in PC or any other hardware problem?

Tags: live-usb, hardware, data-corruption

Had windows before. Got memory management & bad header etc blue screen errors. Now using live Ubuntu persistent USB. Unable to copy large files(>1GB) in  system ,it  freezes the PC  and had to force shutdown. Unable to install OS into hard disk from live USB ,it shows this error

> the following file did not match it's source copy on the CD/DVD :
>
> /target/lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/kernal/driver/media/USB/gspca/gspca_topro.ko
>
> This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD , to burn the CD/DVD at lower speed , to clean CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronic suppliers) to check whether hard disk is old one or in need of a replacement or to move the system to cooler environment

and some times

> *Error no 5 Input/Output Error
>
> This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD , to burn the CD/DVD at lower speed , to clean CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronic suppliers) to check whether hard disk is old one or in need of a replacement or to move the system to cooler environment

. I am able to create folders and copy

small files into hard disk though

And the result of command **lsblk** is

> NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
>
> loop1    7:1    0 852.1M  0 loop /rofs
>
> sdb      8:16   1  14.3G  0 disk
>
> └─sdb1   8:17   1  14.3G  0 part /cdrom
>
> zram3  251:3    0 989.1M  0 disk [SWAP]
>
> zram1  251:1    0 989.1M  0 disk [SWAP]
>
> sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
>
> loop0    7:0    0     4G  0 loop
>
> sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
>
> ├─sda2   8:2    0 778.8G  0 part
>
> └─sda1   8:1    0 152.8G  0 part /media/lubuntu/F517-6AFB
>
> zram2  251:2    0 989.1M  0 disk [SWAP]
>
> zram0  251:0    0 989.1M  0 disk [SWAP]

Output of ***mount*** is

> *sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
>   proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
>   udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4035852k,nr_inodes=1008963,mode=755)
>   devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
>   tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=810292k,mode=755)
>   /dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (rw,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
>   /dev/loop1 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
>   aufs on / type aufs (rw,noatime,si=c1a4b3edf9c769cc)
>   securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
>   tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
>   tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
>   tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
>   pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
>   efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
>   systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=26,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=884)
>   mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
>   debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
>   hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
>   fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
>   tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
>   tmpfs on /run/user/999 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=810288k,mode=700,uid=999,gid=999)
>   gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=999,group_id=999)
>   /dev/sda1 on /media/lubuntu/F517-6AFB type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=999,gid=999,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)*

And i tried to copy a file which is about 1 gb from ***/home/lubuntu/Downloads*** to ***/media/lubuntu/F517-6AFB/DC*** which gave a freeze and i had to force shutdown the pc.

*** sudo fsck /dev/sda1***

> *fsck from util-linux 2.28.2
>   fsck.fat 4.0 (2016-05-06)
>   0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
>   1) Remove dirty bit
>   2) No action*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I'm sorry but It's unclear (at least to me) what "it shows this error." means. Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and then [edit] detail into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Yeah sorry I have added an image which I had to remove due to low points as an new here. Now I edited the question

Comment: No problem. Thank you for the clarification. Did you by chance [verify the ISO](http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso-14-04-through-16-10/503788#503788) that you made your installation media from?

Comment: Yeah I checked it. I am able to login to live session and use it normally. I have Ubuntu 16.10, 15.10 ,elementary OS .. In every OS I am having file transfer problem

Comment: You may be having a problem with the target drive. Have you checked [SMART status?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-10/528077#528077)

Comment: @ElderGeek I'll check and inform u

Comment: @ElderGeek  the result of smart check shows threshold not exceeded and disk is OK and last test was aborted... I just tried to install lubuntu on hard disk now it showed Error no 5 input output error with same message in question

Comment: You might want to let the test complete. If the last test was aborted your results are likely not current.

Comment: @ElderGeek I did a short smart analysis test n I got .. Last self test completed successfully and threshold not exceeded and disk is OK

Comment: @ElderGeek Yes i have done as u said.

Comment: @ElderGeek done

Comment: Please run `sudo fsck /dev/sda1` and [edit] the output into your post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56624/discussion-between-abdul-khalik-shaik-and-elder-geek).

Answer (score 0):

Your having trouble with /media/lubuntu/F517-6AFB which corresponds to /dev/sda1. 
If the drive is mounted unmount it by issuing the command `umount /dev/sda1`
then `sudo fsck.vfat -a /dev/sda1` which will do an automatic repair of the filesystem utilizing the safest means possible.

You haven't defined what you mean by small files, but I should tell you that the FAT family of file systems has limitations regarding file size that make it a poor choice in many cases. FAT 32 is limited to files 4GB in size.

Other possibilities include a bad cable or damaged drive. You can confirm by testing it in another system. If the problem follows the device try replacing the cable on your USB device. If that fails, It's possible that the drive is good but the electronics in the USB enclosure are bad. You can confirm this by swapping enclosures, or connecting the drive directly to the internal connectors in a desktop. If the problem doesn't follow the drive, plug it into a different USB port (preferably on a different bus)

Comment: thanks for your help..  It may be one of reasons what you said... But now my PC is not even starting... It just shows press esc for start menu.. And when I press ESC it shows "ESC.. Pause startup" n just freezes

Comment: Can you boot live media?

Comment: No not even that