# After flashing Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS on an Intel Joule, it still stucks in the

Tags: boot, system-installation, intel

I have a problem with installing Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS on an Intel Joule 570x.
I followed the instructions from https ://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/intel-joule (Alternative install: Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS) step by step, but when it comes up to point 3 (booting from the EFI eMMC Device), it seems, that I didn't install anything on the board. First of all I get the message "Please remove the installation medium, then press ENTER". But after removing and pressing Enter I stuck here.
[This is a development image! Do not use in production.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYLIV.jpg)

Am I doing something wrong, or does anybody else has this problem?

PS: I'm totaly new with this and this is my very first question. So if I forgot something to add or made a mistake, please let me know.

Comment: The Warning is exactly that it's telling you that the image is a development image and may be unstable. This is odd as 16.04 LTS was released a year ago. From your picture it looks like it begins to boot. Please review [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso-14-04-through-16-10/503788#503788) for how to determine if your installation ISO was corrupted in some fashion (or you don't have the ISO you think you do)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Elder Geek! My ISO seems to be OK. Is it possible, that I made a mistake by updating the BIOS? I used the instruction of https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/intel-joule again. Updating the BIOS again results in: 
- Provisioning the eMMC... 
- WARNING: Provisioning failed! Probably already provisioned. 
- Checking for RPMB... 
- Downloading the BIOS... 
- Clearing NvStroage..." 
Is it possible to reset the Joule to its factory settings? I tried it with the Boot Maintenance Manager, but it changed nothing.

Comment: Your new questions aren't related to Ubuntu so off-topic here, however the answers you seek appear to be [here.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/hardware/joule/support) I highly doubt that your ISO is OK. Please reread the second sentence in [my previous comment.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/900730/after-flashing-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-lts-on-an-intel-joule-it-still-stucks-in-th?noredirect=1#comment1412873_900730)

Answer (score 0):

From your picture, it showed the OS is Ostro XT which is shipped with Intel Joule. I am wondering if you remove the microSD card before installation?

Another thing is during the installation, you could choose the target device in a drop-down list. If the board have a microSD installed, the list should show multiple items. Make sure you have chosen the correct media. I do remember the microSD is listed before the eMMC storage.