# Problems installing Ubuntu on an AMD motherboard with a Ryzen processor

Tags: system-installation

I built a new machine using the AMD Ryzen 5 1600 CPU, an Asus Prime B350-plus motherboard and 16GB RAM. Windows runs on it, but of course I want to dual boot it with Ubuntu or Linux Mint.

The error I keep during install has to do with the squashfs unzipping. You can find the error here:

[image]

I have downloaded several versions of Ubuntu and Linux Mint and all of them have this error. I have tried it on several USB sticks and I have used both UNetbootin and Rufus to put the downloaded ISOs on the USB sticks. It always stops with this error.

Comment: Try adding `acpi=off` to the boot options and see if that helps. I think you press F6 during Ubuntu's initial boot to get to the boot options menu.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried when using the 16.04.03 iso

Comment: 1. You want UEFI mode: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI 2. In order to install in UEFI mode, the USB stick must be made to support it and has to be booted as such. 3. Kernel parameters if required are to be edited on the boot entry (with Try Ubuntu selected press 'e' to edit and add the parameter(s) in the same line where 'quiet splash' is). It's possible you have defective USB sticks and/or compatibility problems (try USB2.0 ports instead, etc.)

Comment: Have you by any chance [checked the hash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso-14-04-through-17-04/503788#503788) on your downloaded ISO(s)?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: did you also try with alpha version of Ubuntu 17.10 (uses kernel 4.12)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the speed of the memory. Allthough it is DDR4 2400mHz the problem was solved when I clocked it down to 2133 mHz. Now the system is running and is rock solid.