# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Installer Won't Boot

Tags: system-installation

I bought a Dell Inspiron 3552 that came preinstalled with windows 10, it's 64-bit.

The problem is that I hate windows and would love to try Ubuntu however the installer won't boot, tried launching it as a live USB but it won't boot up.

Help?

Comment: Did you verify that the [hash matched](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso-14-04-through-17-10/503788) before you [created your live USB?](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your USB is not in the "Boot List" of devices.
Try to go into the BIOS to change it.