# Ubuntu LiveUSB kernel panic

Tags: boot, kernel, live-usb, checksums

I successfully booted into the 18.04 Live USB, but any time I select an option, including "Check disk for defects," it spits an "End kernel panic" error. Any fix for this?

PS: I did download another ISO and used that, with both Rufus and Pen Drive Linux's Universal USB Installer. No dice.

Comment: run a checksum on the iso

Comment: Related:https://askubuntu.com/a/503788/225694