# Lubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64 USB installation goes to a black screen | laptop model: Eluktronics P670RP6

Tags: lubuntu, 18.04, 64-bit

How to replicate:

Using a Eluktronics P670RP6 laptop, create bootable USB device using Rufus-3.1p. Download lubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso and use these options to make the bootable USB - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDkKM.png. Restart your laptop and boot using the USB drive. Click either try Lubuntu or install Lubuntu and the screen goes black.

The problem is that cannot get passed the screen that lets you try Lubuntu live or install. Sometimes the screen turns black and other times it shows the Lubuntu logo for a moment then goes black.

Specs:

- Laptop Model: Eluktronics P670RP6
- System Type: x64-based PC
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 2801 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
- BIOS Version/Date: American Megatrends Inc. 1.05.01 12/02/2016, 12/2/2016
- SMBIOS Version: 3.0
- Embedded Controller Version: 255.255
- BIOS Mode: UEFI
- Secure Boot State: Off
- Installed Physical Memory (RAM): 32.0 GB
- Video Card #1: Intel Graphics 630
- Video Card #2: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060m

I've inserted "nomodeset" before the splash text but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: It may have defect in bootable pendrive. Can you check Live USB with “Check disk for defects" option ?

Comment: Yes, I've done this a few times with different USBs. I'll dig around for anymore USB drives I can try.

Comment: Before you get too carried away trying different flash drives you might want to [check to see if you have a valid ISO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso-14-04-through-18-04/503788)

Comment: Just verified the ISO is fine. ec8326dae77750685c3364d2503a46de *lubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix the issue where the screen goes blank. Within my bios, I switched my graphics option to discreet, from hybrid.

Now I get a different error message, but this problem is solved.